# Using Socket.IO, how can I find out the session ID of a disconnected user?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

When a user disconnects from the server, how can I find out the session ID?

At the moment I’ve got an ugly method of asking all existing clients to send a message back.

e.g. on the server:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    // What’s the sessionid?
});
```

Comment: I don't think my answer provided enough to actually answer the question, so I deleted it. But, I think that the link may help: http://chrissilich.com/blog/socket-io-0-7-sending-messages-to-individual-clients/ In short, some hackery with socket.id.

Comment: Thanks – it doesn’t seem immediately obvious so was expecting a bit of hackery!

Comment: See http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

will give you the ID of the socket which was closed, but this is probably more of a hack... :)

Comment: what does it mean if this is "undefined"?

Answer (score 8):

You can attach any data to socket when connection is made:

```
var clients = {}
var client_id = 0;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.client_id = client_id; // or your `session_id`
  socket.anyData = "foobar";
  clients[client_id] = socket;
  client_id++;

  socket.on("disconnect", function() {
    console.log(this.anyData) // prints: foobar
    delete clients[this.client_id];
  }
}
```